# Why do we need to use a 100ohm differential probe to measure ethernet signals when there is not any standard?

Tags: voltage, resistors, ethernet, termination, phy

I was going through the debugging techniques of ethernet signals and found that we can capture the ethernet signals using a 100ohm differential probe.

[image]

Why do we need to add 100ohms on the differential probes to measure the ethernet TX and RX signals when there's no termination standard mentioned for the ethernet TX and RX signals on the board?

Am I misreading the standard termination for ethernet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN2759.pdf) is a typical Ethernet schematic showing the PHY components.

Perhaps you can see the 100\$\Omega\$ differential impedance termination. The transformer ratio is 1:1.

[image]

Comment: Oh, so the 2 49.9ohms together are the 100ohm termination right?

Comment: Is there any standard that says the ethernet signals need to have 100ohm terminations on the differential pair lines (like say CAN standard of 60ohms or LVDS of 100ohms) ?

Comment: Yes, the Ethernet standard, 802.3 etc

Comment: IEEE 802.3 specifies the impedance. Another standard specifies the cable to be 100 ohm differential impedance (+/- some tolerance like 15%).

Comment: Thank you for the comments and answers!

Comment: If one doesn't use resistors terminations ... there should be more errors on the lines ... and more repeating "packets" ... so lowering the speed of transmission exchanges  ...